# Synonym for "series" with distinguishable singular and plural forms

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I need a word which could be used instead of "series" when we talk about books, movies, computer games. The word should have distinguishable singular and plural forms.

An example passage:

> My favorite book series (plural) are *Harry Potter* and *The Lord of the Rings*.
>
> *The Lord of the Rings* series (singular) consists of 3 novels.

I'm going to use "set"/"sets", but I'm not sure it is the best possible option.

Comment: Could you explain why, please?  We can manage with many nouns that have no plural form:  sheep, deer, even fish (as in “my favourite fish is tuna, my favourite fish is Griselda).  A writer’s skill lies in finding a way to avoid avoid ambiguity  deftly.  For example:  My TWO favourite book series are X and Y.

Comment: @Tyffy, In my case, it's for database. The database have "Books" and "Book", "Authors" and "Author" tables; all of them are used side-by-side for different purposes. But it's not possible to have 2 tables with the same name, and here the problem with "series" arise.

Comment: I see.  In a sense, you are trying to create a three-dimensional grid.  And the Latin 5th declension (‘res’ -= thing- , plural ‘res’) is getting in the way.   But there is more to it.  Lord of the Rings is actually a trilogy, and there are other ‘series’ in that sense, like the Alexandria Quartet,  which is a Tetralogy of 4 novels linked by a single theme or story.  Then you have the Potter novels, which are a set of distinct adventures with the same characters.  So Agatha Christie has the Poirot series and the Miss Marple series.  But the order in which you read them is not crucial.

Comment: So perhaps the categories need a bit of a think in any case.

Comment: I think *set* / *sets* is fine. Another word to consider is *collection* / *collections*, which works since the context is books. However, would the complete collection of *TLotR* include *The Hobbit* and *The Silmarillion*?

Comment: @Tuffy. ”The Fifth Declension” is the name of the action thriller book series I now dream of writing, set in Rome, where the major plot twist is when the protagonist discovers that what everyone thought was a singular heist was a deep ongoing conspiracy.

Comment: Also  “sequence” vs ”sequences” if the concept of ”series” implies an order.